# Sorting xml document in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'd like to sort the following xml document using powershell.

```
<car>
<germany>
    <manufacturer>Opel</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>BMW</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Benz</manufacturer>
</germany>
<japan>
    <manufacturer>Nissan</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Daihatsu</manufacturer>
</japan></car>
```

So the elements inside germany and japan should be sorted.

Ideally I'd like to read the xml from the file system, and overwrite the existing doc with the sorted one.

Comment: Where does the `<car>` tag start and end?

Comment: Oops!!! Forgot about that, sorry. Right after </japan>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably many solutions. One quick is this one:

```
$xml = [xml]"<car>
<germany>
    <manufacturer>Opel</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>BMW</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Benz</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>b</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>a</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>c</manufacturer>
</germany>
<japan>
    <manufacturer>Nissan</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Daihatsu</manufacturer>
</japan></car>"

$g = $xml.car.germany| select-xml 'manufacturer' | Select-Object -expand Node | sort '#text'
$j = $xml.car.japan | select-xml 'manufacturer' | Select-Object -expand Node | sort '#text'

@"
<car>
<germany>
    $( ($g | % { $_.OuterXml}) -join "`n`t" )
</germany>
<japan>
    $( ($j | % { $_.OuterXml}) -join "`n`t" )
</japan></car>
"@
```

Note that I used `Select-Xml` to extract manufacturers from the xml, because `$xml.car.germany.manufacturer` returned just array of strings (you probably had problems with that). I wasn't able to get the original object, even with help of `PsBase` property. That's why I used `Select-Xml`.

Comment: What's wrong with using `$g = $xml.car.germany.manufacturer | sort`?

Comment: `$xml.car.germany.manufacturer | sort` returns array of strings. Did you mean to recreate the xml like `$xml.car.germany.manufacturer | sort | % { '<manufacturer>'+$_+'</manufacturer>' }`? I found the `OuterXml` approach cleaner in case there would be some other attributes/elements inside. Or - are you able to get original `XmlElement` from `$xml.car.germany.manufacturer | sort`? I didn't :|